# Python Chess Board (easy)

Tags: python

I'm kind of newbie in coding, so i'm a ltittle bit not stack but confused with this Python chessboard task.
I think i made a little "overdo" with code.

So here is a task: 
Given two cells of a chessboard. If they are painted in one color, print the word YES, and if in a different color - NO.
The program receives the input of four numbers from 1 to 8, each specifying the column and row number, first two - for the first cell, and then the last two - for the second cell.

And here is my code:

```
h1 = int (input()) #first cell height
w1 = int (input()) #first cell width
h2 = int (input()) #second cell height
w2 = int (input()) #second cell width

#Guessing first cell color
if ((h1 % 2 != 0) and (w1 % 2 != 0)) or ((h1 % 2 == 0) and (w1 % 2 == 0)):
    one = str ('black')
else:
    one = str ('white')

#Guessing second cell color
if ((h2 % 2 != 0) and (w2 % 2 != 0)) or ((h2 % 2 == 0) and (w2 % 2 == 0)):
    two = str ('black')
else:
    two = str ('white')

#compare two cells
if one == two:
    print ('YES')
else:
    print ('NO')
```

Something is telling me that it can be much more simple then current version.

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se]. If not, please clarify the problem with a [mcve].

Comment: You don't need to cast strings to `str`. Strings are already strings.

Comment: You can try something like `if (h1+w1) % 2 == 0` to check if it's a white tile, else it's a black tile. Same goes for `h2` and `w2`.

Comment: Basically you can print the result right away after the if condition, so there is no need to use the "one" and "two" variables for this. You can write 
if ((h2 % 2 != 0) and (w2 % 2 != 0)) == ((h2 % 2 == 0) and (w2 % 2 == 0)):
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")

Comment: Thanks for answers. Sorry for  posting working code not in Code Review. In future will do so.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
h1 = int(input())
w1 = int(input())
h2 = int(input())
w2 = int(input())

def is_same_colour(h1, w1, h2, w2):
    if ((h1 + w1) % 2) == ((h2 + w2) % 2):
        print('YES')
    else:
        print('NO')

is_same_colour(h1, w1, h2, w2)
```

It uses the fact that the sum of the row and column of a cell is even when the cell is black, and odd when it's white.